# If God is not like His creations, how should we understand His emotions?

Tags: allah

In the Quran, God says there's nothing like Him.

> And there is none comparable to Him [[Quran 112:4](https://quran.com/112/4)]

However, in many other verses, we find that God expresses human, or human-like emotions ranging from anger to mercy and so on.

So, how should we understand God's emotions given that he does not resemble His creations?

Comment: But the thing is the one who created us is Allah.he can fit in our logic and can not fit in our logic both I the same time.

Comment: @DarkKnight Don't think this answers my question, sorry. I'm sure some scholars have commented on this issue, I was rather looking for a scholarly answer.

Comment: OK, when I saw the question even I wanted an answer

Comment: Well, then upvote it so that it gets more visiblity :)

Comment: yes you are correct in will upvote it

Comment: are you try to understand god's emotions?

Comment: Basically, yes. When God says he's angry, is he angry like he's a human? If so, then isn't He like us in a sense? If not, then what's his anger like? How's it different than man's anger? Similar questions apply to his mercy and so on.

Comment: Maybe it might be not possible to fully understand it, however, perhaps, there are better explanations out there that can bring us a step closer to the truth.

Comment: I got you.. allah sent prophet and quran for how we will lead our life... there are everything.. if you do good work allah will be happy and reward you, if you do bad work, allah will not be happy/angry with you.allah  will give punishment for your bad work... It's better  ask more specific question

Comment: @SpiderRico maybe, I think it is just a metaphor(anger) for us humans to understand why God does this. Because if he just Punish people, it will be hard for us to understand. MAYBE